# ¿Cerrar definitivamente una sesión de ApplicationCookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, identity

Como puedo cerrar definitivamente una sesión desde OnValidateIdentity, he intentado utilizar context.RejectIdentity() pero a recargar la aplicacion esta recupera el logeo...

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {  
                OnValidateIdentity =  context =>
                {
                    var URL = context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                    var user = context.Request.User;
                    if (URL.ToString() == "http://localhost:55383/Home/Contact")
                    {
                        context.RejectIdentity();
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método estático signout:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: Disculpa, sabes como podria lograr en esa parte algo parecido a
validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromHours(1),